# How JQuery data validation plugin works on the submit action

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am learning how to use JQuery validation plugin, 
and came across some questions
 about the JQuery magic that works on the sumbit action.
I got a simple HTML form which has got an input text field like this:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
<input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The magic happened when I tried not to input any data into the field and pressed the
submit button. I saw an error message in red pop up, 
and no matter how hard and how many times
I pressed the submit button, nothing was submitted.

It seemed that there were some scripts that disabled the submit action,
but I just couldn't find which lines of codes in the JQuery Validatyion Plugin that did it.

I want to learn how it works from examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is change the submit button to a button button that way your not confusing the action.  After which, you will manually submit the form once it validates.  It will look something like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

  //form validation setup
  var setupFormValidation = function(){

      //bind the click event to the new button with id submit-form
      $("#submit-form").click(function(){
          submitForm();
      });

      //setup validation on commentForm
      $("#commentForm").validate({
          errorLabelContainer: $("div#formerror"),
            rules: {
               name: { required: true }
            },
            messages:{
               name: "please enter your name"       
            }
     });

  }

  //define submitForm function
  //this manually submits form
  var submitForm = function(){
    document.cmxForm.submit();
  } 

  //document loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //set up your form validation
    setupFormValidation();            
  }); 

</script>

</head>


<!-- add your form error div -->
<div id="formerror"></div>


<!-- added name = cmfForm -->
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="" name="cmxForm">
<input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />

<!-- changed from submit to button with id of submit-form for jquery -->
<input type="button" class="submit" id="submit-form" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try following to understand this:

put this in the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){confirm("Are you sure ?");});
});

</script>
```

you will see that, if you click in cancel, submit action doesn´t happen.
This is why when you return false in the button, you cancel the postback, when you return true, the postback happens.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking at the [examples](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) for JQuery Validate, the following code kills the submit action.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});
```